# Adding last average value

Tags: java

I'm having trouble adding the last number of the loop that I have. I don't have any ideas how to include the last number and then add it to the double variable and then divide it to make the average. I would use my IDE to solve the problem but the input has to be approximately 1000 trials in order to be accurate. You can plainly see that 10 trials of 3.0 or higher does not equal approximately 2.8. I just need to have the missing trial added and then calculated into the average.

Code:

```
import java.util.*;

public class CalculatePI2

{ 

public static boolean ifitisInside (double xPosion, double yPosion)  

{  

    double distance = Math.sqrt((xPosion * xPosion) + (yPosion * yPosion));
    return (distance < 1.0);

}



public static double calculatePI (int numThrows)
{ 
    Random randomGen = new Random();    
    int hits = 0;
    double PI = 0;
     double Alpha=0;
     double average= 0;
    for( int m=0; m<10; m++)
    {
        Alpha=+PI;  
        average= m/Alpha;
        if(m>=0)
        {
            hits=0;
            PI=0;

    for (int i = 0; i <= numThrows; i++)

    { 

        double xPosion = (randomGen.nextDouble()) * 2 - 1.0;
        double yPosion = (randomGen.nextDouble()) * 2 - 1.0;
        if (ifitisInside(xPosion, yPosion))

        {
            hits++;
            double dthrows = numThrows;
            PI =+ (4.0 * (hits/dthrows));


        }
    }
           System.out.println("Trial["+m+"]: ="+ PI);

}



}
 System.out.println("Estimate:"+average);
return PI;
}
    public static void main (String[] args)
    {
        Scanner pie = new Scanner (System.in);
        System.out.println("This program approximates PI using the Monte Carlo method. By simulating throwing darts at a dartboard. ");
        System.out.print("Please enter number of throws: ");
        int numThrows = pie.nextInt();
        double PI = calculatePI(numThrows);




}
}
```

Comment: `Alpha=+PI;` Fairly certain that was supposed to be `Alpha += PI;`. Change it and check if it works.

Comment: @ValekHalfHeart Not it makes the average less than 1

Comment: I'm sorry, should've been `X`.  I will re-post my comment, since it's too late to edit.

Comment: If `M(n)` is an average of `n` values and `X` is another value to add, then `M(n+1) = (M(n)*n + X)/(n+1)` within your precision

Comment: Wasn't able to solve the problem. I'll just move on and leave this question unanswered 12/29/13

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just take the average computation out of the inner loop. Also, the loop invariant is from 0 to < numthrows, not <= numthrows. Also, your initialization of the variables needs to happen for each of your 10 trials, so it needs to be moved inside the loop.

```
double sumPiOverMTrials = 0;
for( int m=0; m<10; m++)
{
  double hits = 0;
  for (int i = 0; i < numThrows; i++) { 
    double xPosition = (randomGen.nextDouble()) * 2 - 1.0;
    double yPosition = (randomGen.nextDouble()) * 2 - 1.0;
    if (ifitisInside(xPosition, yPosition))
    {
      hits++;
    }
  }
  double pi = 4.0 * hits/numthrows;
  System.out.println("Trial["+m+"]: ="+ pi);
  sumPiOverMTrials += pi;
}
System.out.println("Average over "+m+" trials ="+ sumPiOverMTrials/10);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can solve this just by rearranging your code:

```
public static double calculatePI (int numThrows)
{ 
    Random randomGen = new Random();    
    int hits = 0;
    double PI = 0;
    double Alpha=0;
    double average= 0;


    for( int m=0; m<10; m++)
    {

        for (int i = 0; i <= numThrows; i++)
        { 
            double xPosion = (randomGen.nextDouble()) * 2 - 1.0;
            double yPosion = (randomGen.nextDouble()) * 2 - 1.0;
            if (ifitisInside(xPosion, yPosion))
            {
                hits++;
                double dthrows = numThrows;
                PI += (4.0 * (hits/dthrows)); // NOTE: += not =+
            }
        }

        Alpha+=PI;  // NOTE += not =+
        average= m/Alpha;
        if(m>=0)
        {
            hits=0;
            PI=0;
        }
        System.out.println("Trial["+m+"]: ="+ PI);

    }
}
```

This way the average is calculated after each trial rather than before. Also, I don't know much about this particular algorithm, but I think that this line:

```
average=m/Alpha;
```

should be:

```
average=Alpha/m
```